# ExtJs - Unable to save a store to localStorage

Tags: extjs, proxy, local-storage, extjs4.2, extjs-stores

I have a store with a localstorage proxy, but I'm unable to save the data.
The code is quite simple:

```
onToolbarTicketsadd: function(me){
    var tickets = this.getStore('Tickets');
    tickets.add({id: 1, name: 'new'})
    console.log(tickets.getById(1), tickets.count())
    tickets.sync({callback: function(){console.log('synched')}})
},
```

The ticket gets added to the store, as the first `console.log` proves, but the `sync()` command does not work. The localStorage inspector only shows an empty entry `Tickets: ''`, and the `callback` function also does not get called.

**What am I missing ? What is necessary for a localstorage proxy to work ?**

Note: The problem is not with the browser: I'm on the latest Chrome and Firefox.

Here is the code for the store and the model:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Tickets', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'App.model.Ticket',
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'Tickets'
    }
});

Ext.define('App.model.Ticket', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

A demo of the problem is [here](http://romanel.bible.ch/ext-test/sandbox/).

Comment: your demo link seems broken, could you provide a fiddle for that? the behavior seems very strange, cause its so basic

Comment: No, it's not broken, it just takes a lot of time to load. Well I found the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the `id` exclusively for your own field name, then manually setting the `idProperty` on the model to something else seems to resolve the issue - see this [working demo](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5an).  Take note though, that if it's required you will have to enforce your own uniqueness on the attribute.

```js
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: '_id',  // <-- here 
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This took me much time to find. The problem is due to the way Extjs determines when a record needs to be synched: the `phantom` property.

To add a new record to a store, you must not give the `id`. This will not work (since the id is set, the record will not be marked as `phantom`, and it will not get synched) :

```
store.add({id: 1, name: 'new'})
store.sync()
```

This will work:

```
store.add({name: 'new'})
store.sync()
```

There is also a possible workaround, by setting the `phantom` property after adding the records. This can be necessary when the `id` has some meaning and is more than just an autoincremented value :

```
Ext.Array.each(store.add({id: 1, name: 'new'}), function(record){
    record.phantom = true
});
store.sync()
```

An allusion to the problem is made at [`Extjs.data.Model.phantom`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-property-phantom): *Any record which has a real database pk set as its id property is NOT a phantom -- it's real.*
It's clear that this statement is not necessarily true, like above in the first code snippet, but since Extjs 4.2 assumes it to be true always, the bug appears.

I hope that this explanation will save somebody some hours of work. It would have saved me a day.

Comment: You are right @Lorenz, the problem is the id property. However your workaround is not okey, phantom is an internal field that you shouldn't modify never ever. If the id property is important then, the model should define a different id property to use internally. Take a look ate the model documentation.